# Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly - Solution has been retracted

Tags: event-receivers

I have a wsp which basically contains a Workflow and an Event Receiver (Item Updating).
I deployed it, and then had to retract the solution.
Now I'm getting an error every time I try to update an item. Looking at Fusion Log, here's the detail:

```
Event manager error: Could not load file or assembly `...` or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have checked and the dll is no longer in GAC, the feature is no longer available, and the solution does not existe anymore, so I don't know who is trying to call this dll.

Any advise?

Comment: I would look into Sharepoint Manager2010 and FeatureAdmin2010 if you have SP2010. Sharepoint Manager will allow you to see if you have event recievers still attached and FeatureAdmin will help you find faulty features in your farm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you retract a solution usling Uninstall-SPSolution (or Central Admin), you may also need to remove the solution file. Even if the files doesn't exist in GAC, reference to them may still be there. Use the [Remove-SPSolution](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607748.aspx) cmdlet.

```
Remove-SPSolution -Identity contoso_solution.wsp
```

> The Remove-SPSolution cmdlet deletes a SharePoint solution from a farm. Before you use this cmdlet, you must use the Uninstall-SPSolution cmdlet to retract the solution files from the front-end Web server.

Comment: Thank you Benny. I wasn't aware of this. I'm not able to test it because I already fixed it by removing other wsp solutions that I thought were causing this. Even though it wasn't the best alternative as I had to deploy these again, at least it was fixed. Although I didn't have the chance to test it, I will mark this as the correct answer because this is great information! Thanks

Comment: @Gonzalo You're most welcome! Haapy SharePointing :)